# no graphics with 6500xt

Tags: boot, 20.04, graphics

I built a new computer to game on recently, and when I try to boot 20.04 off of usb it stops displaying anything.
specs:
i3-12100F
16gb ddr4
rx 6500 xt
update: i tried using safe graphics and it displayed some error:
VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modsetting

mtd device must be supplied

Comment: What do you mean try to boot? Is it booting and there is nothing on the screen? More details are needed. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: its booting just nothing displays.

Comment: Did you download the latest iso? If you're using an older iso this will happen. It sounds like the kernel version or the firmware package being bundled into the USB is too old

Comment: im using the newest lts.